# what boolean value passed to promise.then means

Tags: javascript, promise

I ran across this piece of code - what is the role of Boolean value in then part of this piece of code ?

```
 if (someCondition) {
     return Promise.resolve(oQueryInfo);
  } else {
     return this.myPromiseFunction(par1, par2, true, false).then(onResolve, onReject, false);
  }
```

While `oResolve` and `oReject` are callback functions.

Comment: `myPromiseFunction` returns a `thenable` (something other than `Promise`) which takes 3 parameters

Comment: If it's a native promise, it means nothing - `then` only takes two arguments. Are you using a special promise library maybe?

Comment: Specifications https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then do not mention any third argument..Unless you are overriding the native `then` function, that third argument is useless!

Comment: What does `myPromiseFunction` return?

Comment: returns a either reject or resolve

Comment: The [`q`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference) implementation of `.then` accepts 3 parameters, with the third parameter being an *`onProgress`* handler. I know of no other implementation that takes three parameters.